# Querying multitable data

Tags: sql-server-2005

this is the query i tried to execute but it says couldn't find stored procedure all table.

alltable (SELECT convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)) [Date/Time], [Through], [Amount Received]
FROM Transactions
UNION ALL

SELECT convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)) [Date/Time], [Through], [Amount Received]
FROM DTH
UNION ALL

SELECT convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)) [Date/Time], [Through], [Amount Received]
FROM Utilities
UNION ALL

SELECT convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)) [Date/Time], [Through], [Amount Received]
FROM Mobile
UNION ALL

SELECT convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)) [Date/Time], [Through], [Amount Received]
FROM ISP)
SELECT convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)) [Date/Time], [Through], SUM([Amount Received])
FROM alltable
GROUP BY convert(datetime, convert(char(10),[Date/Time], 101)),  [Through]

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
with AllTables as (
    select dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, [Date/Time])) as Date, Service, AmountReceived from Table1 union all
    select dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, [Date/Time])) as Date, Service, AmountReceived from Table2 union all
    select dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, [Date/Time])) as Date, Service, AmountReceived from Table3 union all
    select dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, [Date/Time])) as Date, Service, AmountReceived from Table4 union all
    select dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, [Date/Time])) as Date, Service, AmountReceived from Table5
)
select Date, Service, sum(AmountReceived) as AmountReceived
from AllTables
group by Date, Service
```

Just be sure, you use `union all` and not `union`.

Comment: The column's name is `[Date/Time]`, not `DateTime`, but basically that's similar to what I was going to post.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be efficient but it will work... first...

select the 3 fields you want from each table and union them together... as a view... then do you sum / group by on the view...

ex....
create view combined
as
Select DateField, Service, AmountRecieved from table1
union
Select DateField, Service, AmountRecieved from table2
union
Select DateField, Service, AmountRecieved from table3
...

select sum(amountREcieved), DAteField, Service 
group by DAteField, Service

GL